# Merge two python dataframes and add first match and stop before proceeding

Tags: python, pandas

For `pandas.merge(df1, df2, on='Col_4')` will operate by **inner join** by default which will take rows on the shared columns that have the exact values in these shared columns.

**Question**: Let us say we have a 4 rows in first `df1` and 3 rows in `df2`. So if all values in the shared columns are the same, then the first row will be added 4 times since we have, so we will have 10 rows for each row from dataframe1. In total, we will have 12 rows.

**Problem**: Is there a way to stop once we find a first match between the first and the second dataframe and move to the second row in the first dataframe please?

[image]

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID':[1,2,3,5,9],
        'col_1': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'col_2':[6,7,8,9,10],
        'col_3':[11,12,13,14,15],
        'col_4':['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID':[1,1,3,5],
        'col_1': [8,9,10,11],
        'col_2':[12,13,15,17],
        'col_3':[12,13,14,15],
        'col_4':['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']
    }
)

pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col_4')
```

So, as below, how to stop please at first match as red rectangle show where we stop once we find a match from df1 to df2 based on shared column `col_4` please? So, the result should be the red rectangles below please:

[image]

Results in dictionary format:

```
{'ID_x': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 2,
  5: 2,
  6: 2,
  7: 2,
  8: 3,
  9: 3,
  10: 3,
  11: 3,
  12: 5,
  13: 5,
  14: 5,
  15: 5,
  16: 9,
  17: 9,
  18: 9,
  19: 9},
 'col_1_x': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 2,
  5: 2,
  6: 2,
  7: 2,
  8: 3,
  9: 3,
  10: 3,
  11: 3,
  12: 4,
  13: 4,
  14: 4,
  15: 4,
  16: 5,
  17: 5,
  18: 5,
  19: 5},
 'col_2_x': {0: 6,
  1: 6,
  2: 6,
  3: 6,
  4: 7,
  5: 7,
  6: 7,
  7: 7,
  8: 8,
  9: 8,
  10: 8,
  11: 8,
  12: 9,
  13: 9,
  14: 9,
  15: 9,
  16: 10,
  17: 10,
  18: 10,
  19: 10},
 'col_3_x': {0: 11,
  1: 11,
  2: 11,
  3: 11,
  4: 12,
  5: 12,
  6: 12,
  7: 12,
  8: 13,
  9: 13,
  10: 13,
  11: 13,
  12: 14,
  13: 14,
  14: 14,
  15: 14,
  16: 15,
  17: 15,
  18: 15,
  19: 15},
 'col_4': {0: 'apple',
  1: 'apple',
  2: 'apple',
  3: 'apple',
  4: 'apple',
  5: 'apple',
  6: 'apple',
  7: 'apple',
  8: 'apple',
  9: 'apple',
  10: 'apple',
  11: 'apple',
  12: 'apple',
  13: 'apple',
  14: 'apple',
  15: 'apple',
  16: 'apple',
  17: 'apple',
  18: 'apple',
  19: 'apple'},
 'ID_y': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 3,
  3: 5,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 3,
  7: 5,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 3,
  11: 5,
  12: 1,
  13: 1,
  14: 3,
  15: 5,
  16: 1,
  17: 1,
  18: 3,
  19: 5},
 'col_1_y': {0: 8,
  1: 9,
  2: 10,
  3: 11,
  4: 8,
  5: 9,
  6: 10,
  7: 11,
  8: 8,
  9: 9,
  10: 10,
  11: 11,
  12: 8,
  13: 9,
  14: 10,
  15: 11,
  16: 8,
  17: 9,
  18: 10,
  19: 11},
 'col_2_y': {0: 12,
  1: 13,
  2: 15,
  3: 17,
  4: 12,
  5: 13,
  6: 15,
  7: 17,
  8: 12,
  9: 13,
  10: 15,
  11: 17,
  12: 12,
  13: 13,
  14: 15,
  15: 17,
  16: 12,
  17: 13,
  18: 15,
  19: 17},
 'col_3_y': {0: 12,
  1: 13,
  2: 14,
  3: 15,
  4: 12,
  5: 13,
  6: 14,
  7: 15,
  8: 12,
  9: 13,
  10: 14,
  11: 15,
  12: 12,
  13: 13,
  14: 14,
  15: 15,
  16: 12,
  17: 13,
  18: 14,
  19: 15}}
```

Comment: kindly add the expected output as a DataFrame or a dictionary that can be converted to a dataframe.Meanwhile you can drop duplicates on the right dataframe before joining: ``df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(subset='col_4'), on='col_4')``

Comment: @sammywemmy. Thank you. You would like me to create a dataframe for the excpected output please? The above results is the output of merge.

Comment: yes, the picture you shared shows the lines you are interested in. Also, does this work for you ? ``df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(subset='col_4'), on='col_4')``

Comment: @sammywemmy. I will add shortly please.

Comment: try this: `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col_4').groupby(['ID_x']).first()`

Comment: @sammywemmy. Yes it worked, so what is the logic in your solution please?

Comment: @Avra, you are only interested in the first match; `drop_duplicates` keeps only the first row for the duplicates; similar to the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get the first entries of each same value of `col_4` in `df2` by [`.GroupBy.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) before merging with `df1`:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.groupby('col_4', as_index=False).first(), on='col_4')
```

Result:

```
   ID_x  col_1_x  col_2_x  col_3_x  col_4  ID_y  col_1_y  col_2_y  col_3_y
0     1        1        6       11  apple     1        8       12       12
1     2        2        7       12  apple     1        8       12       12
2     3        3        8       13  apple     1        8       12       12
3     5        4        9       14  apple     1        8       12       12
4     9        5       10       15  apple     1        8       12       12
```

Comment: @Avra  This seems differ a lot from your description and picture with red rectangles showed in original version.  I think it's a totally new question.

Comment: @Avra  Seems all people who seen your original question had the same interpretation guided by your red rectangles and descriptions and hence guided you in the same direction.  For now, it's a totally different one and need different solution.  I would suggest you post a new question with the updated requirements.  Posting a new question would be the best benefit for you since it attracts more views and probably you get your answer much quicker.

Comment: @Avra  If you change requirement considerably after it is answered,  I guarantee you will be disliked more.  People don't like this practice very much!   Your new post can give different title and describe it differently from your original version (like your edit now).  It's common people ask follow-up actions or modified question, so no problem on that.  Otherwise, pretty sure you can't easily get your desired answer.

Comment: I did that and unrolled all updates. Working on that question now. Thank you. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: This is a follow up question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69518646/merge-two-python-dataframes-and-avoid-adding-same-match-twice-before-moving-to-t

Comment: What is the meaning of `df2.groupby('col_4', as_index=False).first()`  inside merge please?

Comment: @Avra  I deliberately added a link to the official document of `.GroupBy.first()` in my answer.  To learn Pandas features, it's actually a very important step to look at the official document and learn from the descriptions and examples (if any) there.

Comment: @Avra  Actually, I already included what's that do in my answer:  `to get the first entries of each same value of col_4 in df2`